# JS Library installation quits in the middle through MAC terminal

Tags: javascript, macos

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

[image]

I'm using my Personnel MAC and doesn't undergo any proxy setup